# Combobox does not keep selected item after reload

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a combobox listing items from an Observablecollection. It works fine until I change window, everytime the window loads, the combobox reverts to the first item of the list. I would like the combobox to keep the item selected even after reloading the page (i.e. go to a different window and then come back to the first one).
I tried to save the item selected and impose it on the combobox ut in vain, the combobox is reloaded automatically.

```
public ObservableCollection<Order> AvailableOrderings { get; set; }

        <local1:ComboBox  ItemsSource="{local1:Binding AvailableOrderings}" 
            SelectedItem="{local1:Binding SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            DisplayMemberPath="OrderName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="726.4,83,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275"  SelectedIndex="0"  local1:Grid.Column="1"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Height="22" local1:Grid.Row="1"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public Order SelectedOrder
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedOrder;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedOrder != value)
            {
                _SelectedOrder = value;
                _matrixProcessor.SetOrder(_SelectedOrder.OrderName);                    
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedOrder");
            }
        }
    }

 public ViewModelMain()
    {
//.....//
        AvailableOrderings = new ObservableCollection<Order>()
        {
        new Order(_matrixProcessor) { OrderName = "Row,Columns,Sheets" },
        new Order(_matrixProcessor) { OrderName = "Columns,Row,Sheets" },
        new Order(_matrixProcessor) { OrderName = "Sheets,Columns,Row" },
        new Order(_matrixProcessor) { OrderName = "Columns,Sheets,Row" }
        };

        //_matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder() is a property which keeps the user selection
         if(_matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder() !=null && _matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder() != AvailableOrderings.First())
        SelectedOrder = _matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder();
}
```

The combobox starts with the first value of the list every time the page is loaded, I would like it to show the first item only the first time is loaded  and then keep the vale the user selects.
Thank you.

Comment: do you call content initializing before or after you create AvailableOrderings and assign SelectedOrder?

Comment: Your items in the list, and combobox are not the same... Items need to be same. If you instead of SelectedOrder = _matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder set SelectedOrder to SelectedOrder = AvailableOrderings.FirstOrDefault(), then it will show the first item

Comment: @Nawed my problem is that it already shows the first item everytime the window is loaded, even if I change the page and come back. I want it to show the first only on the first load then keep the item selected by the user even if I reload the page.

Comment: Well... With my comment I was hoping to give you a 'aha' moment. Based on your provided code the two lists are not the same. You need to set the SelectedOrder to one of the objects from AvailableOrderings collection. In case you create a collection with each time windows loads, then you have to find your correct object from the new collection. Most likely you can compare with the OrderName

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Except when Order overrides Equals.

Comment: @ Nawaz that is the code I added:            if(_matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder() !=null && _matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder() != AvailableOrderings.First())
            SelectedOrder = _matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder(); with GetSelectedOrder() is a property which takes the item previously selected by the user. I put it in the constructor of the main viewmodel but the combobox seems to reload (with the first item of the list) after it.

Comment: Try SelectedOrder = AvailableOrders.FirstOrDefault(o=> o.OrderName == _matrixProcessor.GetSelectedOrder().OrderName;

Comment: @Nawaz It works! I do not know why but it does. If you wdit your answer I can put it as solved and I invite everybody to upvote this very non trivial answer to a very common problem.

Comment: The reason that works is that two objects with the same properties are not the same (unless you override the Equals function). E.G. someone else with the same name as you is not the same person. The selected item is not in the list, so it cannot be chosen. The solution is to find a list item with a matching name and make that the selected item.